# How to add an imagelist to WPF listview?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, imagelist

I don't even see it in the Toolbox in the designer. Is it called something else?

I am trying to port my winforms listview to wpf.

Comment: can you add an image of your winform listview?

Comment: Yep, using an imagelist control.

Comment: Just wondering, where are your images coming from? E.g., should they be taken from a file, resources, a stream, etc.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ccc3c6de-b02f-4552-bf8e-595b6a01fa97).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that one, but I am not sure where component tray and imagelist component is? It's not in the properties window.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I posted a winforms solution, you need to manage templates to add images, there's no built-in support for image lists anymore.

Comment: Edited the link, check it out.

Comment: Hi @KenanE.K. , Could you edit some content from that page into your answer? [Link-only answers are discouraged on SO because the link could break.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/321006)